# Start a specific chapter on the left page?

Tags: sectioning, chapters, double-sided

Using the `book` class with the `twoside` option, I get chapters that start on right/odd pages, which is the expected behavior.

Still, I would like to have some specific chapters starting on a left/even page. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

the `book` class provides the `openright` switch, which is "on" by default.  if you want to have a chapter start on the left, just before the `\chapter` command, insert

```
\makeatletter
\@openrightfalse
\makeatother
```

make sure this is in the same file as the `\chapter` command.  if the chapter is in a separate file, accessed by `\include`, and the "don't open right" code is in the main file
before the `\include`, the code will be delayed until after the `\include`d file has been
read and processed.

to reset the right-opening mode, do just the opposite:

```
\makeatletter
\@openrighttrue
\makeatother
```

this can be made into a pair of commands, perhaps `\OpenLeft` and `\OpenRight`.

Comment: N.B. as stated at the beginning of the answer, the first code block just turns the default *off*. Hence, calling it `\OpenLeft` might be a bit confusing, because it makes the chapter open anywhere, not specifically on the "left".

Comment: Is there a way to make it a real \OpenLeft?