# How to force only one chapter to start on even page

Tags: sectioning, chapters, book-design

I have quite a long book in which chapters **SHOULD** start on odd pages. But there is final, *About author*, chapter which I want to be printed on reverse side of previous chapter page. In other words, I want that last chapter, and only this one, to break rule about starting only on odd page and instead I want this one chapter to start on even page. I can't use `openany` option of `book` class, because that will cause all chapters to start on any page and that is not what I want.

Example:

```
\documentclass[final]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Regular chapter}
\lipsum[1-10]
\chapter{Next regular chapter}
\lipsum[5-10]
\chapter{Another regular chapter}
\lipsum[1-2]
\chapter{About author (it should start on first free page - which is even one, not odd one)}
\lipsum[3-4]
\end{document}
```

In this example, chapter 2 starts on page 5 (odd page) and chapter 3 starts on page 7, which is all good. But, chapter 4 also opens on odd page (page 9). I want chapter 4 to start on page 8 instead, so when book is printed, chapter 4 is on reverse page of chapter 3 page.

**So, how can I tell LaTeX to start that one chapter on even page?**

Comment: you could use `openany` and add ad `\cleardoublepage` before every _normal_ chapter

Comment: @MaxNoe Thanks. That was my initial idea, but then I thought: *I want to change behaviour of only one chapter, so it doesn't makes sense to add anything to all other chapters to solve this problem.*

Comment: I agree that this would be the least elegant solution.

Comment: It would be nice idea, though, if someone faces reverse situation. And it could be used if you use custom macro to generate chapter headings, because you wouldn't care about how much code you type to achieve your goal.

Comment: similar question: [Start a specific chapter on the left page?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/203720/579)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
\documentclass[final]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Regular chapter}
\lipsum[1-10]
\chapter{Next regular chapter}
\lipsum[5-10]
\chapter{Another regular chapter}
\lipsum[1-2]
\csname @openrightfalse\endcsname
\chapter{About author (it should start on first free page - which is even one, not odd one)}
\lipsum[3-4]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Will this syntax still work if these non-standard chapters appear between other regular chapters?  Or, would you have to use another \csname command?

Comment: @elikakohen that has set the boolean flag to false so will affect all following chapters, you could use `\csname @openrighttrue\endcsname` to set the flag back true again

Comment: Okay, I was beating my brain over this - and it seems like the issue I am having is with the Memoir class.   I am even trying Memoir one sided, and no dice.  Do you have any ideas why this wouldn't work?  Thank you again!

Comment: its best to ask a new question as a new question not as a comment on a 5 year old answer, that way a regular memoir user may see it and give a memoir answer, rather than just pinging me @elikakohen