# Pad odd page to force chapter to start on even page

Tags: page-breaking, chapters, blank-page

I understand the use of [`\@openrightfalse`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208712/how-to-force-only-one-chapter-to-start-on-even-page) to force a chapter to start on an even page. When the previous chapter were to end on an even page, this would force an empty odd page. How do I change the content of the filler page, e.g. to "this page intentionally left blank"?

Comment: Now I see the error, I did not read entirely: `openany` (which sets `\@openrightfalse` then) does not mean that a chapter does start only on even pages then

Comment: What class are you using for your document?

Comment: @Kiraa, probably `memoir`.

Comment: likely duplicate: [Chapter on the right side - How to turn it off?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23625/579)

Comment: @barbarabeeton I don't think the question is a duplicate even though the answer given there addresses this question, too. At least, it may do, if the OP does indeed decide to use `memoir`.

Comment: @cfr -- okay, reasonable interpretation.  here's an alternative which may be more to the point: [How do I make pages which were “intentionally left blank”?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1727/579).  although it's tagged for `koma-script`, there's also an answer for `memoir`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton That looks more likely - or maybe a combination of both.

Comment: @SimonKuang -- the question title implies that you want all chapters to start on an even page, but the text of the question implies that you may just want a message on an empty page before the start of a chapter.  these are a bit contradictory.  it would be helpful if you could be more precise about what you really want, and look at the two questions cited in comments as possible duplicates.  maybe one of them answers your *real* question?

Comment: @barbarabeeton, I think that question you referred to answers mine.

Comment: @SimonKuang -- but which?  the one about "chapter on the right side", or "how do i make pages ..."?  and once that's clear, can we close this one as a duplicate?

Comment: @barbarabeeton, cfr's answer is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this just with commands from `memoir`. If you are using a standard class `nextpage` offers some additional convenience commands, such as `\cleartoevenpage[]`, which work similarly to those defined by `memoir`. Here, `\cleartoevenpage[]` is used in a redefinition of `memoir`'s `\clearforchapter`:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\renewcommand\clearforchapter{%
  \cleartoevenpage[\thispagestyle{empty}A beetle in a box.]}
\begin{document}
\chapter{one}
\kant[1-4]
\chapter{two}
\kant[5]
\chapter{three}
\kant[6-10]
\end{document}
```

[image: Beetles...]