# putting reference page at back on even numbered page with revtex4 class (... or maybe amsart class)

Tags: page-breaking, revtex

I am making booklets with the classes `revtex4` and `amsart`

I would like to find a way to put a particular reference page on the back of the booklet... so that means that the document should end on an even page with a single page of reference notes - so that the reference notes can be seen by turning the booklet over and looking at the back.

I am looking for a solution in `revtex4` class particularly, but would also be interested to know if there is a way to do this is class `amsart`

I looked at a couple of questions about putting the final chapter of a book on the left (even page) rather than right (odd page) see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208712/how-to-force-only-one-chapter-to-start-on-even-page) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/203720/start-a-specific-chapter-on-the-left-page), but the solutions there seem to just mean that the chapter start is not forced to the right and could end up on either side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way of putting a final reference page always on an even page no matter how many pages are in the document by using the package

```
\usepackage{ifthenelse}
```

The code is

```
% Main document above

\label{lastpage}
\clearpage

%Last page = \pageref{lastpage}
\ifthenelse{\isodd{\pageref{lastpage}}}
  {}  %odd
  {{\bf[ This page is intentionally Blank]}\clearpage}    %even

% Now we should be on final even page for reference table

% insert reference page

\end{document}
```

The document needs to be compiled multiple times after edits to be sure to get the right pagenumber for the page before the end.

This method, of course, will not work if a bibliography is placed at the end of the document automatically after the reference page.

I post this answer as I hope it will be useful if someone else wants to do this for a handout booklet, for example.

I also post it so I can mark the question as solved.